# Windows 2008 SP2 x32 is rebooting every 800 minutes , how to know why?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dump

This is becoming a nightmare, we have no clue on why this server is rebooting each 800 minutes.

This issue started on the night from 05th to 06th of January, so it is a kind of present.

I come form the linux world, so I'm a bit lost, let's see if I can explain the situation properly.

First of all, the uptime of this computer: Easy to see a patern.

[image]

Then the event viewer, it's in spanish but and Image is 1K words:

Application events: (only info stuff)

[image]

And system events:(only info stuff)

[image]

We have done a checkdisk , and everything is fine.

Scheduled tasks have nothing weird, in fact there are only the original ones, no scheduled task from ourselves.

No new programs have been installed.

Hardware looks fine.

Windows is licensed.

A friend checked the minidumps and he found nothing.

What else can we check? Is there any automated check to check everything?

**Responding the questions:**

**Filtering on event 1074 :**

[image]

It reboots each day , since 6th of January.

On the 9th I see a planed reboot for update. The eventdata states : C:\a68ceedd0c82c60dade2e4b830b8f9\spinstall.exe

Second time on 9th : unplaned from explorer.exe
Third time on 9th: reboot without titles from winlogon.exe

And so on, all the reboots seen here are planed on the way to try to fix this issue, none of them worked. Would you like to see the details from them? (just ask)

**Number of minutes on the reboot:** 849 minutes each time.

[image]

Remember that we installed some patches and rebooted, so there are a few that do not last for 800 minutes.

Thanks
Marc

Comment: Is the exact value 840 minutes ?

Comment: Can you filter the System log on event id 1074? Anything relevant there?

Comment: answered at the bottom of the main question

Comment: Pull the server, run a memory test.

Comment: Can not shut it down for as long as a memory test. It's a DC. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, it was due to the storage controller doing a self test and failing, causing a reboot. Disabling tests on the storage controller fixed the problem until we replaced the controller entirely.

If this is not the issue, I would still double check the rest of the hardware.

I would also isolate it from the network a couple of minutes before the next reboot and se how this effect it just to rule out external influences and have the server enter the bios/eufi setup menu and see if it reboots after 800 minutes to rule out the OS.

Comment: This controller self test are installed on windows? How do I find them?

Comment: Hardware raid controller*

Comment: I'm back, its an Adaptec AIC-7902B HostRaid driver , I'm trying to find the logs or something to check the times, to see if it matches the reboots.

Comment: Finally the controller was broken, so many thanks for your help, this was a nightmare. :)

Comment: Typical RAID Controller BS. Glad I helped